# How to upload image to custom location using models.ImageField and attribute?

Tags: django, django-models

I am an absolute beginner with Django so here is my question:

- I created a model and I have `image = models.ImageField()`. When I use the admin interface, every uploaded image is placed in the root directory.
- I read through this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/ and if I use the below example it still doesn't work.

  ```
  from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

  fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/static/images/gallery')

  class Car(models.Model):
      ...
      photo = models.ImageField(storage=fs)
  ```

The new entry is correctly added but when I click the image name, the following error is displayed, and the image is not placed in /static/images/gallery

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Library/book/12/change/002_user_experience_remastered.jpg/change/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.change_view
book object with primary key '12/change/002_user_experience_remastered.jpg' does not exist.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

My code as I wrote it:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/static/images/gallery')

class book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    otherDetails = models.URLField()
    availableCopies = models.IntegerField()
    borrowUntilDate = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(storage=fs)
    commentName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    commentText = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

My project has the following configuration:

```
..\Services
    Services
    Library (my app)
    static
    templates
    venvs
```

From the admin interface I load pics from C:\pics and I want them to be stored in ..\Services\Library\static\images\gallery folder.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`? Just realized the example is from django, could you post your code?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to review my question. I edited the original post, and added more information. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

From the documentations:

During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from `MEDIA_ROOT` using the `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()` view.

This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment strategies, see [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).

For example, if your `MEDIA_URL` is defined as `/media/`, you can do this by adding the following snippet to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to review my question. I am not sure I understand your answer. I modified the original post and added some more information. When explaining things to me, please consider that this is my very first project in python / django and I started to learn the language 2-3 months ago. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the absolute path of your folder in the `FileSystemStorage` location and also provide a `base_url` if you have not set `MEDIA_URL` in settings.

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(
    location='C:/.../Services/Library/static/images/gallery',
    base_url='/gallery/'
)
```

References:
[FileSystemStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class)